# How to remove particular word if containing that character and store in another variable in php

Tags: php

I want to remove a word from string If containing that character and store in another variable. 
Example:

```
$a = 'This is bla bla @@ani bla bla.';
```

So I want to remove word containing @@ and store in another world.

So after removing $a will have 
This is bla bla bla bla.

And @@ani should store in another variable

Any help will greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should separate words then look for the word contains "@@":

```
$a='This is bla bla @@ani bla bla. ';

$array = explode(' ',$a); //containig all words

$result = [];
foreach($array as $value){
    if(strpos($value,"@@") > -1){
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

$result contains all words matching "@@"

**UPDATE:**

now for removing these words from the original String :

```
$finalString = str_replace($result, "", $a);
```

`$finalString` is `$a` but without words containing "@@".

Comment: It successfully stored word. Containing @@ in another variable but now $a variable contains only ok all data before @@ is gone

Comment: Few errors I fixed. First you should separate words then look for the word contains "@@":


    $a='This is bla bla @@ani bla bla. ';
    $fs=$a;
    $array = explode(' ',$a); //containig all words
  
    $result = [];
    foreach($array as $value){
     if(strpos($value,"@@") > -1){
      $result[] = $value;
     }
    }  
$fs=str_replace($result[0],' ', $fs);
$fs contains $a data but word containing "@@" removed 
$result contains all words matching "@@"
It worked now.. Thank u